# Should I use setInterval when fetching data?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, reactjs

I’m trying to learn and then use react in one project. I have a controller (in rails) that outputs json:

```
...
  def index
    @users = User.order(created_at: :desc)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render json: @users}
    end
  end
...
```

And one component that fetches data from this controller like this:

```
...
  fetchData() {
    fetch('admin/users.json', {credentials: 'same-origin'})
      .then(function(response) {
        return response.json()
      }).then(function(json) {
        this.setState({data: json})
      }.bind(this))
      .catch(function(ex) {
        console.log('parsing failed', ex)
      });
  };
...
```

It’s not hard to present this data but what is the best way to allow admins to menage this data? 
For example I must allow admins to delete users. I know how to send the request to the server and delete one user:

```
...
  fetchData() {
    fetch('admin/users.json', {credentials: 'same-origin'})
      .then(function(response) {
        return response.json()
      }).then(function(json) {
        this.setState({data: json})
      }.bind(this))
      .catch(function(ex) {
        console.log('parsing failed', ex)
      });
  };

...
```

But what if there are two admins working on the same list or table and deleting users? Before react I was using redirect_to /some/index.html , the site was refreshed and the admin saw the current state of the database. I’m now trying to avoid refreshing the whole site and my first thought was to fetch data each half second:

```
...
  tick() {
    this.fetchData()
  };

 componentDidMount() {
    setInterval(()=> this.tick(), 500)
  };
...
```

Now the admins make each 0.5 seconds a request to the db and get the current data but is this really a good solution?

Comment: Well, if you want the site to automatically update with data from the server you'll have to setup either a polling solution (which is what you've done) or use WebSockets.

Comment: Given your requirement, my suggestion would be to use a WebSockets based solution, which will update Admin screen whenever a change will occur on server side. Look at SignalR for .Net based solution or socket.js for javascript based solution.

Comment: I will say whats been said before by the other 2 comments, but sockets will be your friend here I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the nature of the data. If you're dealing with fairly dynamic data where it is important for your users to have an up-to-date view of things, then yeah, the comments suggesting setting up a websocket connection to push all updates is a good idea.

However, if you're dealing with data that doesn't change that often, then it's probably overkill. Will you end up with scenarios where a user tries to delete/edit a user that has already been deleted? Yes, but it will likely be very infrequent and these situations can be handled by sending back appropriate status codes and handling them in your ui.